# how to update the file without creating new file

Tags: java, arrays, string, csv

My code does not update the exist file. So i create new file but i want to do with the same file and update it. Anyone know how to do it ? my code is here and a picture of what im doing

```
    try (BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("project-output.csv"))) {
    try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("project.csv"))) {
    String line;
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    String[] cols = line.split(",");
    System.out.println("Please choose a criteria (2-7): ");
    final int subjectToGiveMark = in.nextInt(); // for creativity is 2
    System.out.println("Please enter a mark: ");
    final int mark = in.nextInt(); // which mark should be given
    cols[subjectToGiveMark] = Integer.toString(mark);
    // Here is where you write the output:
    writer.write(String.join(",", cols));
    writer.newLine();
}
writer.flush();
```

}
}

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S0BZv.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do it as follows:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String line;
        List<String> dataLines = new ArrayList<String>();
        final int COLS = 6;
        String[][] data = null;
        try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("project.csv"))) {
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                dataLines.add(line);
            }
            // Initialise data[][] with the data from project.csv
            data = new String[dataLines.size()][COLS];
            for (int i = 0; i < dataLines.size(); i++) {
                data[i] = dataLines.get(i).split(",");// Split on comma
            }

            // Display Sarah's marks in Achievement (15)
            System.out.println(data[2][1] + "'s marks in Achievement (15) is " + data[2][3]);

            // Display Harry's marks in Knowledge (25)
            System.out.println(data[3][1] + "'s marks in Knowledge (25) is " + data[3][4]);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // Update the file
        try (BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("project.csv"))) {
            // Increasing Sarah's marks in Achievement by 1
            int m = Integer.parseInt(data[2][3]) + 1;
            data[2][3] = String.valueOf(m);

            // Decreasing Harry's marks in Knowledge by 1
            m = Integer.parseInt(data[3][4]) - 1;
            data[3][4] = String.valueOf(m);

            //Write the updated data to file
            for (String[] row : data) {
                writer.write(String.join(",", row) + System.lineSeparator());
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Sarah's marks in Achievement (15) is 13
Harry's marks in Knowledge (25) is 24
```

**Original content of project.csv:**

```
Student Id,Student Name,Creativity (10),Achievement (15),Knowledge (25),Documentation (25)
F1233,Bill,8,12,20,18
F2345,Sarah,9,13,22,23
F3456,Harry,9,14,24,24
```

**New content of project.csv:**

```
Student Id,Student Name,Creativity (10),Achievement (15),Knowledge (25),Documentation (25)
F1233,Bill,8,12,20,18
F2345,Sarah,9,14,22,23
F3456,Harry,9,14,23,24
```

**Example of updating the data interactively:**

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
        String line;
        List<String> dataLines = new ArrayList<String>();
        final int COLS = 6;
        String[][] data = null;
        try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("project.csv"))) {
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                dataLines.add(line);
            }
            // Initialise data[][] with the data from project.csv
            data = new String[dataLines.size()][COLS];
            for (int i = 0; i < dataLines.size(); i++) {
                data[i] = dataLines.get(i).split(",");// Split on comma
            }
        }

        // Update the file
        try (BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("project.csv"))) {
            Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

            // Updating existing record
            System.out.println("Updating " + data[2][1] + "'s marks in a subject...");
            System.out.print(
                    "Enter the subject number[2 for Creativity, 3 for Achievement, 4 for Knowledge, 5 for Documentation]: ");
            int col = Integer.parseInt(in.nextLine());
            if (col >= 2 && col <= 5) {
                System.out.print("Enter marks in the subject: ");

                data[2][col] = in.nextLine();

                // Write the updated data to file
                for (String[] row : data) {
                    writer.write(String.join(",", row) + System.lineSeparator());
                }
            }

            // Adding a new record
            System.out.println("Adding a new record...");
            String[] record = new String[COLS];
            System.out.print("Enter student ID: ");
            record[0] = in.nextLine();
            System.out.print("Enter student name: ");
            record[1] = in.nextLine();
            System.out.print(
                    "Enter marks in Creativity (10), Achievement (15), Knowledge (25), and Documentation (25): ");
            System.arraycopy(in.nextLine().split("\\s+"), 0, record, 2, COLS - 2);
            writer.write(String.join(",", record) + System.lineSeparator());
        }
    }
}
```

**A sample run:**

```
Updating Sarah's marks in a subject...
Enter the subject number[2 for Creativity, 3 for Achievement, 4 for Knowledge, 5 for Documentation]: 2
Enter marks in the subject: 7
Adding a new record...
Enter student ID: F4567
Enter student name: Richard
Enter marks in Creativity (10), Achievement (15), Knowledge (25), and Documentation (25): 8 12 20 21
```

**New content of project.csv:**

```
Student Id,Student Name,Creativity (10),Achievement (15),Knowledge (25),Documentation (25)
F1233,Bill,8,12,20,18
F2345,Sarah,7,14,22,23
F3456,Harry,9,14,23,24
F4567,Richard,8,12,20,21
```

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7KfL8.png   it gives this error do you know why ?

Comment: oh sorry there is total 9 column i didnt take ss all of it

Comment: @anacip - If you have understood and tested my code, I don't think it will be difficult for you to find the problem in your code. The main problem I can see is the data in your file are not comma-separated while you have used `line.split(",")` and `String.join(",", cols)` which split and join respectively on the comma.

Comment: If you want to use `line.split(",")` and `String.join(",", cols)`, you need to reformat the data in your file in the way I have done. It's not that you can't split a line on space/tab. If you want to use space/tab in your file (the format in which the data is there in your file currently), you need to split a line as `line.split("\\s+")`. When you do this, you need to write the same amount of space/tab in the file. It will make your code a bit more complex but it's doable. Feel free to comment in case of any doubt/issue.

Comment: Thank you. So if i use space/tab i dont need to use ,  ?  and if i usespace/tab, 
 line.split("\\s+")  is enough for split ?

Comment: `line.split("\\s+")` will be enough for splitting a line into values as long as values itself do not contain space(s) e.g. `line.split("\\s+")` won't work correctly for the header line (as the values in header line contain space) or e.g. if a student name has space in it. In that case, you will need a different regex other than `\\s+`. That's why I said that it will make your code complex. I highly recommend you use `,` instead of space/tab to separate values.

Comment: how can i change the number instead of increasing in update file ? Im doing with scanner so that user can put any number he wants and it automatically changes to that number ?

Comment: I've posted an example of increasing and decreasing the value but you can use this method to do any operation. Think of a 2-D array as a table. Then, you will be able to change any cell. Let me post an update so that you can understand it in a better way.

Comment: thank you im waiting your example because when do it says java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 1 out of bounds for length 0

Comment: I've posted the update. First, you test the program with my data (the data which I've posted under the heading, **Original content of project.csv**) and then try to change the code as per the data in your file.

Comment: One more thing how can i add a new student ? if you can help this too i would be appreciate

Comment: I've updated the answer to demonstrate entry of a new record as well.

Comment: Thanks it worked but after that  it deleted all the other names except the created new one

Comment: @anacip - There is not any such problem. I had posted the answer after testing it and I've tested it again now. Did you test the program with my data (the data which I've posted under the heading, **Original content of project.csv**)?

Comment: your last line writer.writer it needs bufferedwriter so i added bufferedwriter maybe thats why it deleted because otherwise i cant use that

Comment: and there is an error in arraycopy do you know why ?

Comment: Did you check the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy(java.lang.Object,%20int,%20java.lang.Object,%20int,%20int))?

Comment: i dont know it says Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: arraycopy: last source index 7 out of bounds for object array[1]
 at java.base/java.lang.System.arraycopy(Native Method)
 at assignment_05.project.main(project.java:132)   ?

Comment: I suggest you post a new question for this problem so that this Q&A can remain clean. Also, a new question attracts more attention from contributors as it is focussed to a specific problem.

Answer (score 0):

can you try

```
// Read existing file 
CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(inputFile), ',');
List<String[]> csvBody = reader.readAll();
// get CSV row column  and replace with by using row and column
csvBody.get(row)[col] = replace;
reader.close();

// Write to CSV file which is open
CSVWriter writer = new CSVWriter(new FileWriter(inputFile), ',');
writer.writeAll(csvBody);
writer.flush();
writer.close();
```

Comment: is there a other way instead of using CSVReader ?